# preg_replace by group in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a string

`$cmd = "java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type *file_type* *original_file* > *new_file*";`

And I want to replace like below

`java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type css css/style.css > css/style.min.css`

What I did is

```
$cmd = str_replace("*original_file*", $v, $cmd);
$cmd = str_replace("*new_file*", "$k", $cmd);
$cmd = str_replace("*file_type*", "css", $cmd);
```

I'm looking for a sort way like `preg_replace`. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: preg_replace_callback with the regex `\*[^*]+\*` will help you out, see https://regex101.com/r/mH4qD9/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any reason why a regular expression should make sense here. Instead I suggest you simply use the str_replace function in its ability to make multiple replacements at once:

```
<?php
$subject = 'java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type *file_type* *original_file* > *new_file*';

$catalog = [
  '*file_type*' => 'css',
  '*original_file*' => 'css/style.css',
  '*new_file*' => 'css/style.min.css'

];

var_dump(str_replace(array_keys($catalog), $catalog, $subject));
```

The output obviously is:

```
string(78) "java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type css css/style.css > css/style.min.css"
```

This is a simple and robust approach and should be *much* more efficient than using regex based pattern matching.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to my comment, you could use the following regex:

```
<?php
$cmd = "java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type *file_type* *original_file* > *new_file*";

$replacements = array(
    "file_type" => "something else",
    "original_file" => "original",
    "new_file" => "new");

$regex = '~\*([^*]+)\*~';
# look for a star literally
# capture everything that is not a star to group 1
# look for the closing star

$cmd = preg_replace_callback($regex,
    function($match) use($replacements) {
        return $replacements[$match[1]];
        # return the new value with match as key
    },
    $cmd);
echo $cmd;
// output: java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar --type something else original > new
?>
```